# Proving a function has a discontinuity at 0 but continuous elsewhere

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity, solution-verification, real-numbers

Let $f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} x + 2 & -3 < x < -2 \\ -x -2 & -2 \leq x < 0 \\ x + 2 & 0 \leq x < 1 \end{array}\right.$

I want to show that $f$ has a discontinuity at $x=0$ but is continuous at all other points in $(-3,1)$

Attempt:
If $f$ was continuous at $0$ then $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = f(0)$. Now $f(0) = 2$. Not sure how to then proceed. Do I just then say $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = x+2$ (since x = 0?)

Hence it is discontinuous at $x = 0$

For continuity at all other points: let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Then there exists $ \delta > 0$ such that $|x - y| < \delta \Rightarrow |(x+2) - (y+2)| = |x - y| < \epsilon$ (let $\delta = \epsilon$).

Also there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - y| < \delta \Rightarrow |-x -2 - (-y -2)| = |y - x| = |x - y| < \epsilon$.

Hence $f$ is continuous at all other points in $(-3,1)$.

Comment: Writing, e.g, $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=x+2$. makes no sense.  The left hand is not a function of $x$.

Comment: As a suggestion:  consider the two one-sided limits.  In order for $f(x)$ to be continuous at $0$, both of those limits must exist and they must coincide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x<0$, $f(x)=-x-2$ and
$$l_{x<0}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)=-2$$

For $x\geq0$, $f(x)=x+2$ and
$$l_{x\geq0}\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)=2\rightarrow$$

$$l_{x<0}\neq l_{x\geq0}$$

hence, the function has a discontinuity at$0$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f(x)=-x-2$ when $x\in[-2,0)$, you have$$\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=-2\ne f(0),$$and therefore $f$ is discontinuous at $0$.

The only other point of $(-3,1)$ at which $f$ could be discontinuous is $-2$. But it is continuous at $-2$ since$$\lim_{x\to-2^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to-2^+}f(x)=0=f(-2).$$